# How to run wepback with projects in subdirectories?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, config, resolve

I have a subdirectory `subdir` with this file:

```
// subdir/local.js
document.body.textContent = 'hello from subdir/local.js'
```

and local `webpack.config.js`:

```
// subdir/webpack.config.js
const { 
  createConfig, 
  entryPoint, 
  setOutput } = require('@webpack-blocks/webpack')

const devServer = require('@webpack-blocks/dev-server')

module.exports = createConfig([
  entryPoint('.'),
  setOutput('./bundle.js'),
  devServer(),
])
```

The same config works in the root directory. However, running locally

webpack local.js

leads to the error:

```
ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' . in /Users/dmitrizaitsev/Dropbox/Sandbox/webpack-blocks-test/subdir
 @ multi main
```

How can I fix that error and run webpack with  projects in subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

Although webpack uses a extended version of nodes `require` for [module resolution](http://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve), it will not resolve `local.js` by default. I would assume that if you were to rename local.js to `index.js` that this would work. Otherwise you could just set the entrypoint to `./index.js` or `./index`.

Comment: Thanks, it only works locally with the `entry` configured in `webpack.config.js` (both `index.js` and `local.js`) but not when file is passed from CLI. Ideally, I would prefer just one config file in the root, that would let me use it locally in any subdir.

Comment: You can do that by setting/changing the [context](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context) property